# How to compare a character of a text in C?

Tags: c, file, text, char

I've a simple program that read all the text file characters and during the reading, it excludes some characters.

Here an example to make it clear

This is the content of my txt file:

```
a b c d e e
f g d h i j 
d d d e e e
```

I want to remove the character 'd' and the space after it to get this result:

```
a b c e e
f g h i j 
e e e
```

My program didn't remove the character 'd' and its space after it reads.

This is the code I'm using to open and read the txt file:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if(argc==2)
    {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
        int c;
        char x = ' ';

        if (file == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while(x != 'd')
        {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if( feof(file) )
            { 
                break ;
            }
            printf("%c", c);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you haven't set the `x` value in the while loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `if`for conditional print.

Also, make your infinite loops obvious.

Comment: It removes the character 'd', but how do I remove the space after the 'd'?

Comment: just add an fgetc into the else part?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the space by simply doing an fgetc.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if(argc==2)
    {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
        int c;

        if (file == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            if(c == 'd')
            {
                fgetc(file); // Skip space
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", c);
            }
        }

        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```